# Visual Basic with .net 5 now shows a dll information message box when running from a command prompt

Tags: vb.net

I recently had my Visual Studio and Visual Basic upgraded and now using .net 5. I have created a program that will run as a batch program. This new program has a .exe and .dll associated with it, plus some json files associated with it. When I run it from a DOS prompt, I see this message first thing:

[image: Dll message box]

It tell me the name of the DLL in a message box that says Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core on the top line. How can I stop this from occurring? This program needs to run unattended so no one is there to ok it?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce your complaint with a console app project template. Post some code

Comment: Use Debug > Break All and show us the content of the Debug > Windows > Call Stack window.

Comment: This was a WIndow Application when I run with a screen, but if I pass a parameter to the batch run of the program, it hides all screens and just auto runs.  Maybe I need to have two versions? Console app and Windows App?

Comment: So this is a windows application, but I run it with a /AUTO option that will not show the screen, but I did run it from Visual Studio and did the Break all then the message appeared. All I see in the code stack window is [External Code].  I do see a slightly different message. Then message box now shows c:\user\name\sorce\repos\Miser OnOff Batch\bin\release\net5.0-windows\Miser_Online_Offline.dll.